# Schedule Email using Agenda

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail, nodemailer, agenda

I am trying to schedule to sent out an email using NodeMailer and Agenda, however, I don't see anything happening with the below code in `index.js`:

```js
var Agenda = require('agenda');
var agenda = new Agenda();
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

agenda.define('send email', {priority: 'high', concurrency: 10}, function(job, done) {
    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
            pass: 'xxxx'
        }
    });

    // setup email data with unicode symbols
    let mailOptions = {
        from: '"Test" <xxxx@gmail.com>', // sender address
        to: 'xxxx@gmail.com', // list of receivers
        subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
        text: 'Hello world ?', // plain text body
        html: '<b>Hello world ?</b>' // html body
        };

    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, response) {
        console.log('Message sent: ' + response.message);
        transporter.close();
        done();
    });
});

agenda.on('ready', function() {
    agenda.every('5 seconds', 'send email'); 
    agenda.start();
});

agenda.on('start', function (job) {
    console.log("Job %s starting", job.attrs.name);
});

agenda.on('complete', function (job) {
    console.log("Job %s finished", job.attrs.name);
});

console.log('Wait 10 seconds...');
```

When I run the above code using `node index.js`, i see the following console message

```
Wait 10 seconds...
```

Basically, I am trying to schedule the email functionality to run for every 5 secs.

Where am I doing wrong?

EDIT: It seems to be with the job implementation versus:

```
 agenda.every('5 seconds', jobName);
```

I need the job object after the fact though, so if there is a way to get that from running the above command, that would be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Agenda calls the 'ready' event when it successfully establishes it's mongo connection. I don't see you setting that up. Something like:

```
 var Agenda = require('agenda');
 var mongoConnectionString = "mongodb://127.0.0.1/agenda";
 var agenda = new Agenda({db: {address: mongoConnectionString}});
```

Comment: I am not referring to mongo here, just smtp server

Comment: Ignore my other comment, I thought I was in an entirely different question. Agenda relies on mongo. It's where it stores all of it's jobs. So if you aren't setting up mongo, they aren't going to run.